# finding friends' birthdays in python

Tags: python, datetime, module, comparison

I have found help with starting an assignment that I previously did not know how to begin. I currently need to figure out a way to compare several birthdays with the current date, as prompted by the user, with the last day of a month as prompted by the user. I know there is a date timemodule that can tell the current date but I am unsure of how to use the module to work with what the user inputs...if that makes sense.

For example: If the user inputs 11/27/18 as the current date and June as the comparison month (my professor requires a month be entered instead of a date), I need to compare the birthdays from an opened file with 11/27/18 and 06/30/19 and print however many of those dates occur before July 1st, 2019 (it needs to be printed in words, my professor requires specific formatting).

I know how to format the dates that are input in my program, but I am unsure how to compare the dates from the file with what is input for comparison as it could be different every time. Currently what I have now is the inputs of strings where the user would prompt the current date and the month and I have the file opened.

Comment: Break it up into smal pieces

Comment: What have you tried so far? If we know what you're starting with, we can help you improve from there

Comment: You should start by showing what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As explained in the introductory tour, this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers, *not a help forum*. Please take the tour, visit the help center and especially read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) to learn how to use this site effectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your program would look something like this its not exactly what your criteria is but this is a step in the right direction. This is just one way to do it so someone might have a better program.

```
FriendList=[" name 1", "name 2"]
PhoneList=[ " 123" , "456"]
Birthday=["January" , "February"]
print(Birthday)

Date=input(" please choose a month or press q to exit")
# in lists the first string or number  in each list will be together
# example: if janurary is chosen then name 1 and 123 will appear


while Date != 'q': # runs until q is pressed to quit
    for i in range (2):# loop goes through the 2 names in the list
        if Birthday[i] == Date: # compares the list of names to the date
            print(FriendList[i],"" , Date[i], "" ,PhoneList[i])
    Date=input(" please choose a month or press q to exit")
```

Comment: Instead of `for i in range(2)`, where `2` is the length of `FriendList`, I think it would be better to just use the length of the list for the range: `for i in range(len(FriendList))`.  That way the code does not need to be changed when `FriendList` has the number of elements changed.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check the dates, start by figuring out this part: "birthday between the current date and the last day of a month "

Once you have that working, loop through the friends, and if they meet the condition then add them to a new list.

Sort the new list by alphabetical order, and print it.

This should give you an idea of where to start, once you've some code you can post that and ask for help for specific problems, but nobody will do your final for you (that's cheating!)